# What are the diffence between virsh, virt-install, and virt-manager?

Tags: kvm, virtualization, libvirt

I know all of `virsh`, `virt-install`, and `virt-manager` can manage the virtual machines. However, what are the difference between the three?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[`virsh`](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.2/Virtualization/sect-Virtualization-Commands_for_Red_Hat_Virtualization-virsh_the_command_line_interface_tool_for_virtualization.html) is a command line interface that can be used to create, destroy, stop start and edit virtual machines and configure the virtual environment (such as virtual networks etc)

[`virt-install`](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.2/Virtualization/sect-Virtualization-Installing_guests-Create_a_guest_using_virt_install.html) is a command line tool that simplifies the process of creating a virtual machine.

[`virt-manager`](http://virt-manager.org/) is a GUI that can be used to create, destroy, stop, start and edit virtual machines and configure the virtual environment (such as virtual networks etc).

#### References

- [Manage virtual machines with virt-manager](http://virt-manager.org/)
- [libvirt - ArchLinux Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/libvirt)
- [virsh command line reference](http://libvirt.org/sources/virshcmdref/html-single/)